# How to manually trigger a cloudwatch rule with ScheduleExpression(10 days)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to setup "AWS::Events::Rule" in cloudwatch with ScheduleExpression(10 days), and write some code to test it, but I can not change the "10 days" to 1 minute or call the lambda function directly. I know that we can call put event for calling a rule with EventPattern. 
But not know how to do that for ScheduleExpression.
Any comment is welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's no possibility for you to manually trigger the rule and make it execute the lambda function. What you can do is change the frequency from 10 days to 1 minute, let it execute, and when it executes switch it back to 10 days

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. I checked AWS document and it says that a rule can only contain [either EventPattern or ScheduleExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html#cfn-events-rule-eventpattern). But in order to call `aws events put-events` we must provide a Source for EventPattern match. So I think we cannot manually trigger a scheduled event.

Not sure what's your use case, but I have decided to move to use [Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#invoke-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest-) API of AWSLambda client.

Answer (score 0):

**SDK Approach:**
Yes, you can use the putRule SDK function to update the ScheduleExpression of the CloudWatch Rule. As I mentioned in the below snippet

```
   let params = 
    {
       Name: timezoneCronName, /* required */
       ScheduleExpression: cronExpression
    }
        
        return CloudWatchEvents.putRule(cloudWatchEventsParams).promise().then((response) => {
       console.debug(`CloudWatch Events response`, response);
       return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.error(`Error occurred while updating Cloud Watch Event:${error.message}`);
        throw error;
    });
```

See this Official AWS SDK [DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putRule-property).

**CLI Approach:**

Run the following command though CLI

```
aws events put-rule --name "You Rule name (not full ARN)" --schedule-expression "cron(0/1 * * * ? *)"
```